# Django queries using a list

Tags: django

I would like to run a query in django using a list. I found a similar post on stack overflow that got me to where I am now, but I can't seem to get my code to work. I think the only difference is that I am using REST. 
My code below is throwing the error `unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'Build' and 'Build'`

What I am expecting is that the query will return all entries where the author_id matches any value in the machinesOwned list.

```
from .models import Build
import operator
from functools import reduce

class buildStatsAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):#for build stats
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = buildStatsAPI_serializer
    def get_queryset(self):
    machinesOwned = [4,5,7,9]
    query = reduce(operator.and_, (Build(author_id= item) for item in [machinesOwned]))
    return Build.objects.filter(query,deleted = 0,).values()
```

Comment: What is `Build` here? It looks a bit strange that you query with `Build(..) & Build(..)` etc as a filtering object? Should these be `Q` objects?

Comment: Ah yes that is part of my issue I think. However I changed to `query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(author_id= item) for item in [machinesOwned]))` and it returns :
`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create a list of `Q` objects, but you might be able to do this a bit more efficiently another way:

```
Build.objects.filter(
    deleted=0,
    author_id__in=machinesOwned,
).values()
```

Otherwise if you're set on your current approach:

```
from django.db.models import Q
query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(author_id= item) for item in machinesOwned))
Build.objects.filter(query,deleted = 0,).values()
```

Comment: I sure love this community! Thank you for the solution. Your first suggestion is much more efficient, and works as I expected